# Why does my gardenia look deformed and have dark spots on the flowers?

Tags: plant-health

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain why my Gardenia is blossoming like this?

Comment: Can we have an image of the plant itself please, including flowers present on the plant, and can you say whether there are other symptoms on the leaves - also where you are in the world.

Comment: Kindly add some more details so the answer is appropriate to your situation.  The picture shows a flower but how old is the flower.  Do the dark spots show up while flowering or towards the end?  Is this happening on all the flowers or only some.

Comment: Welcome Vix! I know we keep asking for more pictures.  It looks like you tried to post a second picture but it didn't work. I tried to adjust the imgur number but couldn't get it.  Can you try again? If there's any way we can help, let us know.

Answer (score 3):

That flower looks old and bruised.  Just touching the petals will sometimes bruise them and won't show up until the flower gets old.  Was this flower like this when it opened?  The stamens look spent as well, so this flower IS old, yes?  Flowers are short term perishables.  Sometimes florists will chop those stamens off to prolong the life of a flower.  Something about the pollen on the petals seems to quicken maturity and the flower gets old faster.  Let's send a picture of the entire plant, that might help us 'see the big picture'!